# Validate single hyphen in the middle

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have the following regex to test if characters input is capital letter and number only

```
const isCapitalLetters = value => /^[A-Z]/.test(value);
```

How do I test if I want to allow only single hyphen can be enter in the middle of the string and not at the end or beginning.

Comment: `^[A-Z]` only checks if a string starts with an uppercase ASCII letter and "allows" any special chars afterwards.

Comment: You check regex containing three groups. Starting group should only allow letters, middle group letters and hyhpen and the last group again only letters.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
/^([A-Z0-9]|[A-Z0-9]+-?[A-Z0-9]+)$/.test(value)
```

(The part before the '|' ensures that a one-character string will pass the test)

Comment: So: start with a capital: `[A-Z]` then zero or more capitals and/or digits: `[A-Z0-9]*` then at most 1 hyphen: `-?` then one or more capitals and/or digits `[A-Z0-9]+` together with the single capital case: `/^([A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*-?[A-Z0-9]+)$/.test(value)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test for captial letters and numbers only with an optional hypen not at the start and the beginning, could do it like this:

[`^[A-Z\d]+-?[A-Z\d]*[A-Z\d]$`](https://regex101.com/r/PPPsvG/1)

- From the start of the string `^`
- Match an uppercase letter or a number one or more times `[A-Z\d]+`
- Match an optional hyphen `-?`
- Match an uppercase letter or a number or an hyphen zero or more times `[A-Z\d-]*`
- Match an uppercase letter or a number `[A-Z\d]`
- The end of the string `$`

If you would allow a single character, you can us a non capturing group and an or `|` to first check for a single single upper case character or a digit:

[`^(?:[A-Z\d]|[A-Z\d]+-?[A-Z\d]*[A-Z\d])$`](https://regex101.com/r/OR9LhQ/1)

Comment: this regex will accept value such as this one `SDFSDF--WERWER`. Two hypen in a string

Comment: @MuhaiminCS I see, I have updated my answer. If you want no number at the beginnin, you can use [`^(?:[A-Z]|[A-Z]+-?[A-Z\d]*[A-Z\d])$`](https://regex101.com/r/G0Lq3G/1)